# Google Analytics iOS SDK V0.2 Beta Canceled timer with interval

Tags: ios, google-analytics-api

I am using Google Analytics for my Ipad App. I did everything as documentation said and is working. In AppDelegate, I setup dispatchInterval to 20 seconds with

```
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
```

It is firing and I am able to see a spike in Google Analytics page. But it is happening only once. Then in Console, I am getting

(GAIDispatcher.m:422) DEBUG: Pending hit queue drained.
2013-05-17 15:37:28.849 xxxxxx[3584:c07] GoogleAnalytics 2.0b4 -[GAIDispatcher cancelTimer] (GAIDispatcher.m:224) DEBUG: Canceled timer with interval 20.0s

And it just stops. not triggering Analytics anymore. Can anybody help me with this. Why is it happening?

Answer (score -1):

The timer is cancelled probably because there is no messages to send to GA

reference: http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-iOS--Day-30%E2%80%93Adding-Google-Analytics-to-your-App